# Scheduling gFTP Download

Tags: linux, linux-mint, scheduling

My current set up involved two HP laptops running Linux Mint 13 (one 32-bit, the other 64-bit) and a Mint 13 server in the cloud. I have been using gFTP for transferring files without problem. However someone has created a huge file on the server that I need to get back to the office – tests suggest that the download would run for ~5 hours! The issue I have is that it would use 40% of my monthly allowance. Although the package is unlimited after hitting your allowance it is throttled back which could have serious consequences towards month end. Data transfers between 12:00 a.m. and 06:00 do not count towards the allowance. Is it possible to schedule gFTP to do a transfer in that timeslot. As the offices are secured from 10:00 p.m. To 07:00 a.m. coming in is not an option.

Thank you...

Answer (score 0):

I hope I'm not mistaking but why don't you set up a cron job with the following command on that specific time?

`gftp [options] [[proto://][ user : [pass] @] site [: port ][/ directory]]`

or maybe you can use `at` command?

[Why do we need the "at" command in Linux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/97882/why-do-we-need-at-command-in-linux)

Comment: Pandian - please could you give an example as I am struggling to get the syntax totally correct. For example if I want to download  the file BlipBop from /home/fred/data at the IP 100:99:10:256 with username MichaelJohn and password abcq23. Thank you...